# How to: 1 Cron Job every ODD minutes and 1 other every EVEN minutes?

Tags: cron

I have 2 cron jobs, i want one of them to run every odd minute (1,3,5,7,9,11....57,59)
and i want the other one to run every even minute (0,2,4,6,8,10,12...58)

how can i do it in an easy way? (no scripting - just cron job rules)

Answer (score 96):

```
*/2 * * * * date >>/tmp/even
1-59/2 * * * * date >>/tmp/odd
```

Comment: whoops! i bet you supplied the correct syntax for the "1-59/2" part... can i ask why when i enter this in cpanel it doesnt work? It says "Cron field not formatted correctly..."

Comment: I don't use cpanel, but I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that the filter they have placed between you and the actual crontab doesn't see it as valid.  It really is though, I typed that exactly into my crontab on a CentOS5 server and got the even minutes in in /tmp/even and odd minutes in /tmp/odd.  Sorry cpanel's filtering it...

Comment: thats what i suspected too... i ll set it manually... thank you for your help jj33 :)

Comment: FYI, for the 1-59/2 syntax. if you want an explaination see http://stackoverflow.com/a/122499/658023

Comment: This worked fantastic, thank you! I'm setting up a dedicated fan controller I wanted to run one minute at a time (apply power to USB, remove power to USB) and this does exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 6):

```
*/2 * * * * /path/to/foo
*/2 * * * * sleep 60; /path/to/bar
```

Is that that `sleep 60` too much like a script?

Comment: yes its more like a script and for sure it is not "just cron job rules". thank you for your time anyway ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
1/2 * * * * for odd minutes 
*/2 * * * * for even minutes
```

Comment: /tmp/crontab.ojyNoj/crontab":39: bad minute
    errors in crontab file, can't install.

Answer (score 0):

Fo `busybox` `cron` (which is the default cron impl. of alpine linux) there is no possibility I am aware of using just configuration. You can solve it via testing `date` minute part though.

```bash
*/1 * * * * [ $(($(date '+%M') % 2 )) == 1 ] && echo 1 > "/tmp/odd: $(date)"    
*/2 * * * * echo 1 > "/tmp/even: $(date)"
```

What it does?

1. Take a minute part of current date
2. Calculate a modulo
3. Test it and run the job only if the test succeeds